# Selecting date value from input type = 'month'

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given:

```
<input class="inputField_input__2B0dA" maxlength="7" id="establishedYear" data-testid="date-input" type="month" value="">
```

Which on the page is an input field that looks like : ----- ---- [Calendar symbol]

The frist ----- resemble the month, and the next ---- the year => April 2020

But the only way to select the actual date is by clicking on the calendar and clicking on a month

I tried to write the value of the element with the required string using js:

```
//        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
//        jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('establishedYear').setAttribute('value', '2022-04')");
```

Which works until the next action, when i click on another element, the value set  with JS dissapears.

PS. If i try to manually type the date, it would work for the month, but then for the date if fails, it only changes the last char like for 2022 it would type 0002

Also, If i try to bascially click on the calendar icon, then click on the month with selenium, I cant do that because, when I try to create a selector for the date elements from the caledar, I cannot find them on the DOM.

So i click on the calendar icon, no changes to the dom appear(no new elements added to the dom)

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: The dates could be saved in an object, so doing changes to the render won't work for long. (like the dates reset on clicking on another element).
Does it send a GET/POST request? If so, can you just skip the DOM and modify the request data instead?

When you use selenium, did you see changes to the DOM? The dates element might have a dynamic ids / classes, so you might want to modify your selector, select the parent element and then the childs (dates),

Comment: or modifying your selector so it would would fit only these type of elements (the dates, e.g if they have a unique icon inside, or fixed unique structure)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by:

```
    ocupSelfEmpPage.establishedYearInput.click();
    ocupSelfEmpPage.establishedYearInput.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
    ocupSelfEmpPage.establishedYearInput.sendKeys(Keys.UP);
    ocupSelfEmpPage.establishedYearInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

So clicking on the input, then space to open the calendar and up to select january, then enter to save it